# jq: parse result where some properties are empty arrays

Tags: jq

Using [**jq**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), wish to parse results that may include array values

Confused. If data contains an empty array:

```
"connections": []
```

Thought that [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) would be able to parse it with:

```
connections: .connections[]? | { id: .id }
```

For example, `"apps"` is an array, and each `app` is defined with the following:

- `"actions"` array
- `"connections"` array

Here result where `apps` has an `app` instance that contains `connections` as an empty array.

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "id": "1a902fb4-1b43-4df9-b9d7-9b54cd14e2ad",
      "actions": [
        {
          "id": "0dc38f41-49fe-4056-b035-850764733a44",
        }
      ],
      "connections": []
    },
  ]
```

Assume all `apps` have `connections` currently containing empty arrays.

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), parsing `apps` without including `connections` (all currently contain empty arrays), no problem, result is parsed:

```
apps: .apps[]? | { id: .id \
  , actions: .actions[]? | { id: .id }
}
```

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), parsing `apps` including empty `connections`, no results, nothing:

```
instances: .instances[]? | { id: .id \
  , actions: .actions[]? | { id: .id } \
  , connections: .connections[]? | { id: .id } \
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Most prominently, you are missing a vlaid JSON input and a valid jq filter. But looking at the fragments, you might want to wrap some pipelines into parentheses if you want their result to be assigned to an object's field. Also consider [having a look](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map%28x%29%2Cmap_values%28x%29) at the `map` filter.

Comment: checking out `map` now.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, `map(x)` is equivalent (by definition) to `[.[] | x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.connections[]` will stream the elements of `connection`. When using inside an object construction filter, this will create one object per element in the stream.

If there are multiple streams involved, the cartesian product will be built.
If the array is empty, nothing will be streamed (and consequently, the product will be empty; see example at the bottom).

Here's an example:

```
$ jq -cn '{
  a: [ 1, 2 ],
  b: [ 3, 4 ]
}
| { x: (.a[] | . + 10), y: (.b[] | . + 20) }'
{"x":11,"y":23}
{"x":11,"y":24}
{"x":12,"y":23}
{"x":12,"y":24}
```

Note that `?` only has an effect on missing values/properties. An empty array is not missing, it has a value: the empty array itself.

You  probably want to use the `map` filter, e.g. to extract an array of ids from your connections: `{ connections: (.connections | map({id})) }`.

Rewriting the example from above with `map`:

```
$ jq -cn '{
  a: [ 1, 2 ],
  b: [ 3, 4 ]
}
| { x: .a | map(. + 10), y: .b | map(. + 20) }'
{"x":[11,12],"y":[23,24]}
```

---

Empty cartesian product:

```
$ jq -cn '{
  a: [ 1, 2 ],
  b: [ 3, 4 ],
  c: []
}
| { x: (.a[] | . + 10), y: (.b[] | . + 20), z: (.c[] | . + 30) }'
$ # empty
```

```
$ jq -cn '{
  a: [ 1, 2 ],
  b: [ 3, 4 ],
  c: []
}
| { x: .a | map(. + 10), y: .b | map(. + 20), z: .c | map(. + 30) }'
{"x":[11,12],"y":[23,24],"z":[]}
```

Comment: Thank you, `connections: (.connections | map({id})) }` worked great!